# Laravel 8: issues with dateTime (DataTables & Charts)

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, datatable, metronic

This issue is happening across the entire application...

I have datatables & charts:

1. Datatables don't sort by dateTime correctly, aka `Started` Column.

[image]

2. Charts always starts with the latest date...not by order:

[image]

I am using `Carbon` for datatables like this:

```
->editColumn('startDateTime', function ($report) {
   return Carbon::parse($report->startDateTime)->format('d M, Y');
})
```

For the charts, returning data as json then format the date:

```
$data = TrafficViolation::select('id', 'violationDateTime')
            ->orderBy('violationDateTime')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function($data) {
                return Carbon::parse($data['violationDateTime'])->format('M');
            });
```

The column type of these dates are `DateTime` in the database.

What's frustrating is that there is a datatable called `Audit Log` that came with the theme (Metronic 8) and it's sorting the date correctly here (`created at`):

[image]

And looking to its controller:

```
->editColumn('created_at', function (Activity $model) {
    return $model->created_at->format('d M, Y H:i:s');
})
```

Looking at the Model there isn't anything related to `Carbon` or date functions there, noting that the data type of `created_at` is `timestamp`.

I tried:

- Changing data type to `timestamp` instead of `datetime`.
- Copying the same code of `audit log`, no need for `Carbon`, I get an error `format() unknown`.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are overcomplicating things, why don't you just sortByDesc if you need the newest results first I do not understand. You can do this like so:

First in you TrafficValidation model add a casts to datetime

```
protected $casts = [
    'violationDateTime' => 'datetime',
];
```

Then where you return the query just do

```
$data = TrafficViolation::select('id', 'violationDateTime')
        ->orderByDesc('violationDateTime')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function($data) {
            return Carbon::parse($data->violationDateTime)->format('M');
        });
```

And the reason audit log works for sorting is because it by default doesnt look at all at your query sorting, it takes the data and sorts it by itself

Comment: Nice, but when I use plain ```format()``` without Carbon I get 500 server error...```Failed to load resources``` And whatever types of sorting, it always starts with August: https://snipboard.io/rY3eSK.jpg